# Auto Set vs Manual Decrease (How to do both?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, range

This may be a bit complex to understand at first, but please bear with me.
I am making a city simulation game, and what I want to achieve is this:

 1. Look at the healthStat of the city
 2. If it's within a range, set the daysRemaining (meaning the city's lifespan)
 3. Every day that passes, the daysRemaining will be decreased.

Guideline:
healthStat  |  default daysRemaining

-10                   10
-25                   8
-35                   5
-40                   2

I have managed to somewhat do a half-solution to this, however, a problem came up. 
I can only do either the auto setting of the daysRemaining, or the manual decrease - I cannot do both.

Here's my code:

```
if (statsHealth <= -10f && statsHealth > -25f)
            {
                //Enable Health Hazard
                isHealthHazard = true;

                //Set Days Remaining
                daysRemaining = 10;
            }
            else if (statsHealth <= -25f && statsHealth > -35f)
            {
                //Enable Health Hazard
                isHealthHazard = true;

                //Set Days Remaining
                if (daysRemaining > 8 || daysRemaining <= 5)
                {
                    daysRemaining = 8;
                }
            }
            else if (statsHealth <= -35f && statsHealth > -40f)
            {
                //Enable Health Hazard
                isHealthHazard = true;

                //Set Days Remaining
                if (daysRemaining > 5 || daysRemaining <= 2)
                {
                    daysRemaining = 5;
                }
            }
            else if (statsHealth <= -40f && statsHealth > -50f)
            {
                //Enable Health Hazard
                isHealthHazard = true;

                //Set Days Remaining
                if (daysRemaining > 2 || daysRemaining < 0)
                {
                    daysRemaining = 2;
                }
            }
            else if(statsHealth >= -50f && hasIssues)
            {
                //GAME OVER
                Debug.Log("GAME OVER!");
                daysRemaining = 0;
            }
            else if(statsHealth >= 0)
            {
                //No More Health Issues
                isHealthHazard = false;
 }
```

The problem is - whenever a day goes by in my game, if it is within the range of the healthStat (ex: -25's healthStat range is between 8 - 6 daysRemaining), it would decrease. However, if the daysRemaining reached 5, it would reset back to 8 since it is out of range (based on the healthStat).

On the other side, if I disable the autoSetting of the daysRemaining based on the healthStat's range, it would work for the manual decreasing. But how can I set the daysRemaining in the first place whenever the player reaches a certain healthStat?

How can I do both auto set the daysRemaining, and at the same time can be able to manually adjust it?

PS: I know this might be a little confusing, so if you have any further inquiries, please feel free to comment it out and I will surely respond. Thanks!

Comment: The way this is written, if you have more than 10 statsHealth and you haveIssues then it's game over... is that intentional?

Comment: @Ruzihm yes, it was intentional. It functions that whenever hasIssues is true, and the statsHealth reached more than -50, the game is over

Comment: That still seems weird that if `hasIssues` is true, `statsHealth` being -200 isn't game over but `statsHealth` being at 100 is game over, but I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to distinguish determine when you enter or leave a category of health or if you were already in that category. Add a variable that keeps track of what the default number of days were in the last category you were in and only change the days remaining according to the difference between the previous and the new default days remaining.

Also, have a boolean to track of if you were previously outside of any category. That way if you were previously outside of any category, you can just set the days remaining to the default days remaining.

Here's what these changes might look like:

```
private int previousDefaultDaysRemaining;
private bool previousOutsideHealthCategory;

void Start()
{
    previousDefaultDaysRemaining = 1000;
    previousOutsideHealthCategory = true;
}
```

And then....

```
// initialize to some value reasonable for not being health category.
int newDefaultDaysRemaining = 1000;
bool newOutsideHealthCategory = true;

// Determine what category of health you are in now
if (statsHealth <= -10f && statsHealth > -25f)
{
    //Enable Health Hazard
    isHealthHazard = true;
    newOutsideHealthCategory = false;

    newDefaultDaysRemaining = 10;
}
else if (statsHealth <= -25f && statsHealth > -35f)
{
    //Enable Health Hazard
    isHealthHazard = true;
    newOutsideHealthCategory = false;

    newDefaultDaysRemaining = 8;
}
else if (statsHealth <= -35f && statsHealth > -40f)
{
    //Enable Health Hazard
    isHealthHazard = true;
    newOutsideHealthCategory = false;

    //Set Days Remaining
    newDefaultDaysRemaining = 5;

}
else if (statsHealth <= -40f && statsHealth > -50f)
{
    //Enable Health Hazard
    isHealthHazard = true;
    newOutsideHealthCategory = false;

    newDefaultDaysRemaining = 2;
}

// Decrease timer 
daysRemaining -= 1;

if (previousOutsideHealthCategory) 
{
    // We were not in a category previously, just set the days remaining
    daysRemaining = newDefaultDaysRemaining;
} 
else 
{
    // reduce or increase daysRemaining by any category change
    daysRemaining += newDefaultDaysRemaining - previousDefaultDaysRemaining;
}

// remember the new category's days remaining and 
// our outsideHealthCategory status if either changed
previousDefaultDaysRemaining = newDefaultDaysRemaining;
previousOutsideHealthCategory = newOutsideHealthCategory;

// check for critical health status boundaries
if(statsHealth > -10 && hasIssues)
{
    //GAME OVER
    Debug.Log("GAME OVER!");
    daysRemaining = 0;
}
else if(statsHealth >= 0)
{
    //No More Health Issues
    isHealthHazard = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I'm still a bit confused on what the actual flow is - for example what do I do first, and then second, and third, etc. From your answer I may have actually got the solution, but as what I've said I don't know how to sequence it?

Comment: It should be in a sequence where it works now. there's some freedom especially with the checking for critical health status boundaries shown at the end but the others should be in the order they are shown.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I should mention that this code is within Update. Should I put it in a separate function and then just call it whenever, or I could stick with the Update function?

Comment: I noticed your `else if(statsHealth >= -50f && hasIssues)` block only is entered if `statsHealth > -10 && hasIssues` because of the if/else chain before it so I changed my answer to reflect that

Comment: It would probably make `Update` more readable if this code is in its own method but it would still work in `Update`

Comment: Thankssss! I get it a bit now. I'm just confused, the `int newDefaultDaysRemaining = 1000;` will be placed on Update. Would that be okay? I mean, it would fight with the range conditions right? Like it would set it to 1000, and also set it based on the range at the same time

Comment: well, you don't need to set `previousDefaultDaysRemaining` in `Start`, because its only used when `previousOutsideHealthCategory `is false, which means `previousDefaultDaysRemaining` was already set at some point. But you do need to initialize `previousOutsideHealthCategory` to `true` somewhere before `Update` occurs, but not before every single procedure.

Comment: I decided to set `previousDefaultDaysRemaining = 1000;` in start just in case you decide it's useful somewhere else in the code for some reason and it needs to be intitialized somewhere in that case.